# Set QLineSeries from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a `ChartView` declared in qml:

```
ChartView {
    id: testGraph
    objectName: "testGraph"
}
```

I connected it to c++:

```
QObject *loader = engine.rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QObject*>("loader");
QObject *item = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(QQmlProperty::read(loader, "item"));
QObject *chart = item->findChild<QObject *>("testGraph");
```

And I have `QLineSeries` in c++:

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
series->append(0, 6);
series->append(2, 4);
series->append(3, 8);
series->append(7, 4);
series->append(10, 5);
*series << QPointF(11, 1) << QPointF(13, 3) << QPointF(17, 6) << QPointF(18, 3) << QPointF(20, 2);
```

Now how can I connect `chart` to `QLineSeries`. I have tried to cast `chart` to `QChartView` but it does not have `addSeries` method as `QChart`.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/74675/qml-chartview-binding-to-c-data/6

Comment: One solution would be to call `createSeries` from QML and pass the return value value to c++. It returns a `QAbstractSeries` that can be casted to `QLineSeries` if it's indeed a line series. You could then populate it from c++.

Comment: I guess that impossible. Although `LineSeries` derived from `QLineSeries` it's different class. Look [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtcharts.git/tree/src/chartsqml2/declarativelineseries.cpp) for the component source. So you cannot just cast it to `QLineSeries`. The simpliest way to do that is create some proxy function in QML and so add point through this function from C++.

Comment: Yes, after some searching I am also starting to think it is impossible. Maybe I will try to instead use `append` in QML on `emit signal`.

Comment: If you can cast chart to QChartView the QChartView has a method Chart which returns a QChart* that has the addSeries method

Comment: If it's derived from `QLineSeries` then you can cast to it.